# Cant add foreign key constraint, why?

Tags: mysql

Okay so im getting really frustated here, I cant seem to spot the problem.

Here is the problem, Im trying to create the tables Vinter and Sommar, but MYSQL
does not allow me to do so because "Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint
".

And here is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE Stuga(
stugaNr int unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
stugaAdress char(60),
nrOfBeds int,
nrOfRooms int
);

DROP TABLE Customer;

CREATE TABLE Customer(
    customerNr int unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    lastName char(30),
    totalPassengers int
);

DROP TABLE Bokning;

CREATE TABLE Bokning(
    orderID int(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    stugaNr int UNSIGNED,
    customerNr int UNSIGNED,
    passengerNr int UNSIGNED,
    datum int,
    FOREIGN KEY (stugaNr) REFERENCES Stuga(stugaNr),
    FOREIGN KEY (customerNr) REFERENCES Customer(customerNr)
);

DROP TABLE Sommar;

CREATE TABLE Sommar(
    orderID int,
    totalPassengers int,
    sNr int primary key,
    benLangd int unsigned,
    huvudOmkrets int unsigned,
    cykelTyp char(30),
    FOREIGN KEY (orderID) REFERENCES Bokning(orderID)
);

DROP TABLE Vinter;

CREATE TABLE Vinter(
    orderID int,
    totalPassengers int,
    vNr int primary key,
    skidLangd int unsigned,
    stavLangd int unsigned,
    hjalm char(20),
    skoStorlek int unsigned,
    FOREIGN KEY (orderID) REFERENCES Bokning(orderID)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Meh just saw it after I posted it. Forgot to add " int(6) UNSIGNED " on the other orderID's.

Thanks anyways :D